# PHP MYSQL drop down list of column data

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to make a drop down list with the data of one of my columns...i'm wandering if the code below is doing that... (it doesn't work by the way) Thanks very much!

```
<select id="teamlist" name="teamlist">
<?php
        $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=clubresults', 'root', '12345678');
    #Set Error Mode to ERRMODE_EXCEPTION.
    $pdo->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);  



$stmt = $pdo->prepare('Select teamname from members');

   while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
     echo "<option>$row</option>";
   }
 ?>
</select>
```

Comment: well it's giving me an empty list..

Comment: I'm not familiar with PDO but is $row really the value you want to use? or do you need a sub item of $row (as in $row[0]) ?

Comment: tried that just then.. still nothing..

Answer (score 3):

You must execute your statement first before you can fetch results.

```
$stmt->execute();
```

or you can use `query`

```
$pdo->query('select ... ');
```

You can read more [here](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) and [here](http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-PDO.html#7.2)

Answer (score 0):

[Referring this link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php)

You must execute the prepare statement as follows.

```
$sql = 'SELECT name, colour, calories
    FROM fruit
    WHERE calories < :calories AND colour = :colour';
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_FWDONLY));
$sth->execute(array(':calories' => 150, ':colour' => 'red'));
$red = $sth->fetchAll();
$sth->execute(array(':calories' => 175, ':colour' => 'yellow'));
$yellow = $sth->fetchAll();
```

Answer (score 0):

your [pdoStatement::fetch](http://il.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) returns an associative [array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php), you need to select the correct value in your array, not just give the array itself to print, which as you noticed prints as nothing.

```
echo "<option>{$row['teamname']}</option>";
```

is what you need

Comment: Rawkode is right that you still need to issue execute() first as well, don't forget to do that as well

Comment: its giving me 6 options.. the same amount as the amount of entries in the column.. but no words..

Comment: Did you use fetchall because that call will return an array of all the rows retrieved by the query at once instead of one row at a time like fetch. You'd use $row[<rownumbere here>]['name']  in such a case.